# Submit PDF Form to PHP page using SSL/TLS HTTPS?

Tags: php, pdf, ssl, https

I created a form where every employee can submit his personal data, I tried submitting the form through HTTPS but the data doesn't arrive to the PHP file. Is there any way to submit the PDF form securely using TLS or SSL

Comment: How did you verified that the data doesn't reaches the PHP file? How is the submit action configured?

Comment: I am using a javascript action on the submit button which sends all the data as following, when its http, the data arrives the database with no problem, but when its https, request time out!

    submitForm({
    cURL: "https://10.xxx.xxx.xxx/recvForm.php",
    cSubmitAs: "HTML",
    cCharset: 'utf-8'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this,

one you have to add HTTPS headers to PHP script receiving the PDF Form. then simply write the address using HTTPS instead of HTTP